# Can't initialize LambdaExpression with an expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

Question similar to [one by John K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123997/lambda-expression-syntax-vs-lambdaexpression-class), but more specific and the accepted answer doesn't suit my needs.

This compiles fine:

```
Expression<Func<object, object>> specificExpression = (object o) => new object();
Expression generalExpression = specificExpression;
```

And this one doesn't:

```
Expression generalExpression = (object o) => new object();
```

Reported compile error:

`Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' because it is not a delegate type`

`Expression<Func<T1,T2>>` derives from `Expression`.

Now I have a framework with methods accepting all sorts of expressions, i.e. type `Expression`. Being forced to explicitly cast lambdas to the corresponding `Expression<Func<T1,T2>>` on each method call is frustrating.

Any good reasons why this basic OOP behavior is broken in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The conversion doesn't work because the compiler cannot infer which specific expression type you are trying to create.  What if you did this?

```
Expression generalExpression = (object o) => "foo";
```

Should this be an `Expression<Func<object, string>>`?  What about `Expression<Func<object, object>>` or `Expression<Func<object, IComparable>>`?  These types would all be a valid final type for the expression tree, and the compiler doesn't pretend to know what you are trying to do.

You need to cast through the specific type to inform the compiler which type of expression you want to produce:

```
Expression generalExpression = (Expression<Func<object, object>>)
    (object o) => new object();
```

You would see a similar compiler error if you tried this:

```
Delegate generalDelegate = delegate() { };
```

Is that an `Action`, or a `ThreadStart`, or some other kind of no-argument void-returning delegate?

Comment: If you follow this logic, then ``var`` keyword should always generate compile-time errors. ``var o = "abc"`` could be an ``Object``, couldn't it? Somehow, type inference works with ``var`` and all information is actually supplied in my example (argument type and return type could be inferred).

Comment: `var` is specifically defined to declare a variable to be of whatever type the right side of the expression evaluates to.  In this case, the compiler doesn't know what the right side of the expression even is yet!  It could be *any* delegate type or *any* expression type.  In this case, the compiler can use the "expected type" to determine how to handle the right side, but if you use `var` or `Delegate` or `Expression` as the left-hand type, then there is insufficient information for the compiler to resolve the type of the right-hand expression.

Comment: In other words, by assigning the lambda to a variable of type `Expression<Func<object, object>>`, the compiler can take that hint to resolve the lambda as an expression tree that takes an `object` and returns an `object`.  But if you assign to a variable of type `Expression`, that doesn't contain enough useful information for the compiler to understand what type the lambda needs to be converted to.

Comment: The part that lambdas get compiled into expressions _or_ delegates convinces me! Why aren't lambdas _always_ compiled to expressions remains a mystery though (well, for convenience with delegates maybe?). If they were, I'd insist that exact (best-matching) expression type could be inferred.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

`Expression<Func<object, object>> specificExpression = (object o) => new object();`

It is actually an ease of writing that the C# compiler offers to us.

This expression will actually be compiled to something like this :

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>> specificExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<object,object>> ( ... )
```

and as you can see, `Expression<Func<object,object>>` is not a delegate type even if the first expession could induce us in error and let us believe that this is the case.

"Expression" is not of delegate type, so you can't assign it directly a delegate object because the compiler doesn't offer the ease of writing (as it does for `Expression<T>` classes).

Sorry to say that but you have to go the frustrating way.

Riana

Comment: I assume you meant:
``Expression<Func<object, object>> specificExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<object,object>> ( ... )``
If so, then it's useful information. But still,
``Expression generalExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<object,object>> ( ... )`` works fine and that's what I'd want...

Answer (score 0):

The C# compiler evaluates the expression to the least complex form, for example:

```
 var x = (object o) => new object();
```

`x` should be a `Func<object, object>`, not an `Expression<Func<object, object>>`. In this case, the compiler is determining the value is a delegate, and since `Expression` cannot take a delegate (only the `Expression<Func<>>` / `Expression<Action>` types can), the compiler error is thrown.

Also, see @Riana's answer, because the expression form is actuall rewritten by the compiler.

Comment: Actually, trying the ``var`` approach generates compile error ``Cannot assign lambda expression to an implicitly-typed local variable``.

Comment: This will give an error for the same reason that `Delegate x = (object o) => new object();` would give an error -- there is insufficient contextual information for the compiler to determine the type of delegate/expression being created.